# XMLHTTP – Omit Images (Just Raw HTML)

Tags: excel, vba

Using an Excel workbook to pull web addresses from Google. The problem is data usage. The machine appears to be pulling all images on the page. Is there any way to obtain just the raw HTML, and block image retrieval...

```
Dim XMLHTTP As Object
Dim HTML As Object
Dim URL as string

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
URL = https://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Exchange

XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
XMLHTTP.send

HTML.body.innerhtml = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
```

Comment: What about removing these two lines `XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader` .. It is supposed AFAIK that xmlhttp doesn't deal with images.

Comment: Brax, I tested it, but even with those headers removed the images are still pulled. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
Sub Test()
    Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As Object, sURL As String, sOutput As String
    sURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Exchange"
    With http
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
            Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
            With html
                .Open
                .write http.responseText
                .Close
            End With
            sOutput = RemoveImageTags(html)
            ExportHTML sOutput
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function RemoveImageTags(html As HTMLDocument) As String
    Dim objElement As HTMLGenericElement
    For Each objElement In html.all
        If VBA.LCase$(objElement.nodeName) = "img" Then
            objElement.removeNode
        End If
    Next objElement
    RemoveImageTags = html.DocumentElement.outerHTML
End Function

Sub ExportHTML(sInput As String)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .CharSet = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText sInput
        .SaveToFile Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\OutputHTML.html", 2
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So I tested it, all html & images are pulled at “. Send”, not “.Reponse”.  But you suggested utilizing MSXML2.xmlHTTP60 (not MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP). The images stopped being pulled, which I thought was my solution. Only problem is after about 1,000 pulls Google blocks “xmlHTTP60”. Google doesn't block “serverXMLHTTP”; unlimited pulls as long they are 1 second apart. Any ideas…